# Copy or transform certain html elements to new child window

Tags: html, css

I have a need.. On clicking a button my datatable should be viewed in a full screen mode with option to come back to normal. If I am in full screen I shouldnot allowed to work on the parent window. I am not using windows.. I have placed my datatable inside a div. How can I achieve this??

Comment: A lightbox/modal dialog is what you need

Comment: Will that allow my table size also increased?? Let suppose in normal screen it is showing just 10 rows for every page[pagination] on full screen I should get more number of rows possible all or like 100 per page.

Answer (score 0):

try jQuery popup: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Check out the documentation and initialize the dialog on loading the page. Here is a sample fiddle as well http://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/PHX2Y/

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Modal",
        height: 250,
        width: 400,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
```